# Read mutliple data from table and create textboxes in form

Tags: c#, mysql

My table in MySQL is like this:

[image: MySQL table]

I have a panel in my Form, and I want to create a TextBox for each data on this table and write `sikicerik` data to that TextBox's text.
Actually I did it but it creates only one TextBox and selects only the first data on the table.

My code is like this:

```
int count = oku.FieldCount;

reader.Read();
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
        Point txtyer = new Point(x, y);
        txt1.Text = reader["sikicerik"].ToString();
        txt1.Name = i.ToString();
        x = x + 25;
        y = y + 25;
        panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
    }
}
```

It creates just one TextBox and writes "5" in it.

How can I do that repeatedly?

Comment: well you don't need the `while (reader.Read())`, instead, after each for loop iteration, write `reader.Read()`

Comment: @amyn tried, still get the same problem

Comment: can you update the above question with the updated code?

Comment: @amyn i did it.

Comment: move the line `reader.Read()` after the for loop starts

Comment: @amyn now I get "4" :D still one textbox, maybe there is a problem with Points of textboxes ?

Comment: You are creating _count_ textboxes all in the same position. One on top of each other. You never assign your point location to the Textbox.Location property. But this is not the end of your problems

Comment: What is oku.FieldCount? Is it a DataReader.FieldCount? If yes then where do you get the _reader_ variable?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand is that you need to call `reader.Read()` after going through each record. Let's say your result data set has 5 records, so in order to read the 1st record, you need to call `reader.Read()` which would populate the reader object with the appropriate data. In order to read the 2nd record, you need to again call `reader.Read()`. Something like this:

```
int count = reader.FieldCount;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    reader.Read();
    TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
    Point txtyer = new Point(x, y);
    txt1.Location = txtyer;
    txt1.Text = reader["sikicerik"].ToString();
    txt1.Name = i.ToString();
    y = y + 25;
    panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
 }
```

The reason why you may not be able to view all TextBoxes is that you are updating both x and y coordinates of the TextBox. What you may probably want to do is just increment the y coordinate as above and all the TextBoxes would appear vertically. You may also want to resize your form so that the TextBoxes don't get hidden.

Also, as @Steve mentioned in the comments above (which I missed), you need to assign the location of the new TextBoxes created as is done in the code above.

Comment: sorry It is "int count = reader.FieldCount;" .  but still I still got problem there is no "5" and why repeats "7" ? 
http://imgur.com/PZ8V4fw

Comment: what text should be inside in each of the 5 textboxes?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Z1kl07Q.png only "sikicerik". I just want to create automatically 4 textbox(couse of 4 data as u see) and write sikicerik on texboxes

Comment: you mean the data in the column "sikicerik" or the text "sikicerik" itself?

Comment: data in coloumn

Comment: probably something wrong with your query. share that in your question above

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you get the FieldCount from the *reader* variable.

Now in this context you should loop over the read and inside the loop create the textbox for each field retrieved by the original query.

Finally, if you don't set the Location property of the TextBoxes they will be created each on top of the others and you see only the topmost one with the latest value obtained in the loop

```
// Get the number of fields present in the reader....
int count = reader.FieldCount;

// Read one record at time
while(reader.Read())
{
    // Create a textbox for each field in the record
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();

        // Set its location on screen
        // Probably if you have many fields you need to 
        // use a better algorithm to calculate x,y position 
        txt1.Location = new Point(x, y);
        txt1.Text = reader[i].ToString();
        txt1.Name = i.ToString();
        x = x + 25;
        y = y + 25;
        panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);
    }
}
```

If you want to create textboxes only for the field *sikicerik* you have two options. The first one is the recommended because it causes less overhead on your database consist in changing the SELECT query used to build the read to

```
 SELECT sikicerik FROM yourTableName
```

The other option is a simple change to your code. You don't need to loop over FieldCount because you already know that you are interested in only one field

```
// Read one record at time
while(oku.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = oku["soru"].ToString();
    label1.Text = Form2.sinavno;

    // Create the single textbox required for the only field required
    TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();

    // Set its location on screen
    txt1.Location = new Point(x, y);
    txt1.Text = oku["sikicerik"].ToString();
    txt1.Name = i.ToString();
    x = x + 25;
    y = y + 25;
    panel1.Controls.Add(txt1);

    // Repeat the loop for each record.

}
```

Comment: no, its take all datas. I just want to take "sikicerik" and write on textboxes

Comment: Then change the SELECT statement to retrieve only the field you want to get _(SELECT sikicerik FROM yourTableName)_

Comment: well my sql code is longer then that actually Im not selecting only one table

Comment: select * from sorular As s,siklar As e  where s.sinavno=e.sinavno

Comment: its like this actually

Comment: But this query doesn't retrieve the field _sikicerik_

Comment: That structure requires a different query to get the sikicerik field: _SELECT e.*, k.sikicerik  FROM sorular e LEFT JOIN siklar k on e.soruno = k.soruno_ This will extract the records from siklar that are in relationship with the record in solar where the foreign key is soruno

Comment: Well it could work also your statement but better use the more modern syntax JOIN.... The important thing is the loop on while(reader.Read())

Comment: "SELECT e.*, k.sikicerik FROM sorular e LEFT JOIN siklar k on e.soruno = k.soruno" should I write this instead of my sql?

Comment: You need to change to my while loop before.

Comment: And remove that for loop

Comment: naah. I dont understand u :(

Comment: Take my second example and replace your while(oku.Read()) loop with that